# Full list of Blockhashes of Ethereum Blockchain

Tags: blockchain

Is there a way to retrieve a full list of the blockhashes of Ethereum blockchain without downloading a full copy blockchain?

(The naive approach I have in mind is to download the blockchain, use some interface to retrieve the blockhashes of the blocks based on their indices and write them into a file). Is there a better approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like Infura (http://infura.io) and the RPC to pull each block by blockNumber using [eth_getBlockByNumber](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getblockbynumber). If you want to pull all 3,600,000 (or more) blocks, it's going to take a very long time.

Even if you did install a full node and sync the chain and used the RPC directly against a local node it might take quite some time as well.

May I ask, just out of curiosity, why you want the block hashes (as opposed to say the full blocks or the list of transaction which seems more useful)?